# redirect when condition met

Tags: php

I'm having trouble redirecting after a count hits 13.

I have bunch of images that a user can click on to add to their list in the db, when they click, an on click js script fires and triggers updatelist.php.

That part works fine, within updatelist.php I need it to insert and then check the table to see if its reached a count of 13 yet, if so, it needs to redirect to a new page.

The insert works fine, but its not redirecting.  below is my updatelist.php code

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$image = $_GET['image'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_movies cross join tbl_users WHERE image_on = '$image' and username = '$username'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                        {
                            $movieid = $row['id'];
                            $userid = $row['UserID'];
                        }
    $query2 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_movies cross join tbl_users where image_off = '$image' and username = '$username'");   
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
                                {
                                    $mid = $row2['id'];
                                    $uid = $row2['UserID'];
                                }   

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $numrowz = mysql_num_rows($query2);

        if ($numrows!=0)
            {
                $queryInsert = mysql_query("insert into tbl_user_lists (userid_fk,movie_id_fk) values ('$userid','$movieid')"); 

                $query5=mysql_query("select l.* from tbl_user_lists as l join tbl_users on l.userid_fk=tbl_users.UserID where username='$username'");
                $updatecount = mysql_num_rows($query5);
                if ($updatecount == 13)
                    {
                        header('Location: http://localhost/main.php');
                    }
            }
        else if ($numrowz!=0)   
            {
                $queryUpdate = mysql_query("delete from tbl_user_lists where userid_fk = '$uid' and movie_id_fk = '$mid'");
            }




?>
```

Below is the script on the main page that calls the above php page

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.img-swap').live('click', function() {
        var _src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (-1 == _src.indexOf('_on')) {
            $(this).attr('src',_src.replace('_off','_on')).removeClass('off');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src',_src.replace('_on','_off')).addClass('on');
        }

        //  Update server
        $.get( 'updatelist.php?image='+escape($(this).attr('src')));
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please, repair your post (code highlighting).

Comment: What do you mean by "triggering updatelist.php"? Are you doing it via an AJAX call and checking the response? Or do you redirect the user via javascript to your updatelist.php?

Comment: its a jquery script that gets called on the on the home page when a user clicks an image, the jquery takes the name of the image and sends it to updatelist.php to updated the table in the db

Comment: Have you tried doing this as a straight-up POST event, i.e. surround this in an `if( isset( $_POST'button_name'] ) ) { ... }` block? If other words, verify it works without JavaScript/jQuery first, then work on making it Ajax-y.

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
    if ($updatecount == 13)
        {
            header('Location: main.php');
            exit();
        }
```

Basically you were doing an assignment operator rather than a comparison, and you should always call exit() after you redirect.

Comment: header (Location) should be absolute path. Can't be bothered to search it up right now, but it should. :)

Comment: @adam, I think it should be an url, not a path.

Comment: My bad, in my native language, path/url doesn't make much difference in this meaning. Anyway, it should be absolute **url** then. From php.net/header.php: `HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs`

Comment: I've added these but its still not redirecting when the count hits 13.  Also , I've removed the part that checks to see if the count is < 13 near the top of the page.  I've edded the original php to reflect my changes

Comment: just curious. header location gives a 301, 302, or other redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Some problems that might have caused the issue:

1. after `Location:` you should write a full url;
2. `if ($updatecount = 13)` will always return true, use a comparison operator instead (`if ($updatecount == 13)`);
3. no code should be executed after the redirect: add `exit;` after the header line;
4. make sure there's no output at all, or php won't be able to set the header: is your `<?php` opening tag the first thing in the file? Is there no html before?;
5. as a test for counts, when in doubt, always output the result after every loop: it will help avoiding several errors as you start with php, most notably off-by-ones.

Also, I don't know if your application will be publicly accessible: in that case, remember that users are not bound to the options in your html as for the values they can post, so escape your query (or use prepared statements) to avoid the risk of sql injection.

Comment: When I tried 2, it caused it to not insert records if it was below a count of 13.  Thanks for the advice on the sql injection, Thats next to add after I'm able to get the functionality working.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake (corrected) in point 2. Also the outermost parentheses are not to be considered part of the code.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the last two conditionals (if, else if) check for the same condition. the second will never be true, this way.

Answer (score 0):

So you're calling a remote PHP script via JS? I don't think sending a header response to the JS code will do anything in the page that calls it. You could have your PHP script return a predetermined code depending on its result, then redirect in the JS code if the "max" code was returned.

Something like (assuming jQuery is available)

```
<script>
$.get( "your_php_script.php" , function (response){
     if( response == "max" ) {
          // redirect
          window.location="other_page.php";
     }}
);
</script>
```

Comment: I've added this to my home page but am not getting the desired effect.  Does it matter that I already have jquery that calls the same updatelist.php page?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that the snippet above wasn't intended to used as-is. Sorry, I didn't vet the above as functional. It's similar to a login script I had at one point. As for your question, I'd have to see what your HTML source it doing. Maybe you could post some of it in your original question?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm a novice at best at coding and I know absolutely nothing about js and jquery.  I've added the jquery script from my home page that calls the updatelist.php page.  Its at the bottom of my original post.